# Fortran array allocation deletion now incorrect solution

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, gfortran

I am writing a program.  The program solves matrices.  The matrices are as large as the user specifies in the command line arguments.  I want the program to solve very large matrices, so when I was done with all the linear algebra stuff including umfpack, lapack, suitespares, arpack ...  I tried to free up memory space by deleting unused arrays.  I located 3 completely unused arrays, that had only been used to debug other problems with solving the matrix.

When I deleted the variable from the declaration and the the allocation the program started to act different.  The matrix solutions are wrong now.  I've gone back to my backup file and it still works fine.  I am certain deleting the declaration and allocation of unused arrays is preventing my program from finding the correct solutions.

I've been toying with the problem for a few days now.  I really can't imagine how deleting unused arrays is changing the execution of my program.  Any help is appreciated.

```
 program HHSolver
    use MathOperations
    integer :: O, NEV, i, j, k, a, col, row
    integer :: coeff, p, b, NTerms, NextCoeff
    integer :: m, n, symbolic, numeric
    integer :: TermIndex, ido, NCV,LDV, LWorkL, info2,ierr
    double precision :: x, y, sigmai, sigmar
    Character(128) :: String, term, factor
    character(1) :: bmat
    character(2) :: which
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: polynomial        !this stores the polynomial boundary equation      
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: lap           !this stores the polynomial boundary equation      
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: temp          !this stores the polynomial boundary equation      
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: R         !this stores the polynomial boundary equation           
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: vec           !this stores the polynomial boundary equation           
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: lwork         !this stores the polynomial boundary equation           
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: alphar, beta 
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: alphai, work 
    double precision, dimension(1, 1) :: dummy
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: RESID        
    double precision, dimension(:, :), allocatable :: V, z
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: workd, workl
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: workev
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: Ax, DI, DR
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: Ap, Ai
    integer, dimension(11) :: IPARAM
    integer, dimension(14) :: IPNTR     
    integer, dimension(1) :: h
    double precision :: control(20), info(90), tol
    logical, dimension(:), allocatable :: select
    logical :: rvec(1)
    double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: tempvec

    external daxpy, dnrm2, dpttrf, dpttrs, dlapy2
    intrinsic abs

    call get_command_argument(1, String)
    read(String, '(i10)') O
    call get_command_argument(2, String)
    read(String, '(i10)') NEV
    call get_command_argument(3, String)

    write(*, *) 'try to allocate enough memory for full matrices'

    !this is wh the matrix is created
    allocate(lap((O + 1)**2, (O + 1)**2)) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation             
    allocate(temp((O + 1)**2, (O + 1)**2)) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation            
    allocate(R((O + 1)**2, (O + 1)**2)) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation           
    allocate(alphar((O+1)**2)) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation            
    allocate(alphai((O+1)**2)) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation            
    allocate(beta((O+1)**2)) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation              
    allocate(vec((O + 1)**2, (O + 1)**2)) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation             
    allocate(work(8*((O+1)**2))) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation              
    allocate(lwork(2*((O+1)**2), 2*((O+1)**2))) !this stores the polynomial boundary equation           
    allocate(RESID((O+1)**2)) !this stores the initial and last eigenvector
    allocate(V((O+1)**2,20+NEV)) !this stores the eigenvectors
    allocate(workd(3*((O+1)**2))) !this stores the eigenvectors             
    allocate(workl(30*(20+NEV)**2 + 60*(20+NEV))) !this stores the eigenvectors             
    allocate(workev(3*(20+NEV))) !this stores the eigenvectors              
    allocate(tempvec((O+1)**2)) !this stores the eigenvectors               
    allocate(DI(NEV+1)) !this stores the eigenvectors               
    allocate(DR(NEV+1)) !this stores the eigenvectors               
    allocate(select(20+NEV)) !this stores the eigenvectors              
    allocate(z((O+1)**2,1+NEV)) !this stores the eigenvectors

    write(*, *) 'memory for matrices allocated'     

            !create the matrix to be solved
            !solver the matrix

    write(*, '(25F20.5)') DI   !these are the real and imaginary part of solution
    write(*, '(25F20.5)') DR
  end program
```

Everything falls apart when I try to delete alphai, alphar, lwork.  They aren't even being used.

Comment: Please provide us with some code to start with, it'll be much easier to figure out where the problem is

Comment: It didn't let me.  It didn't like the formatting.  Im not changing the formatting on 1000 lines of code.

Comment: What happens if you put the `implicit none` statement at line 3?

Answer (score 2):

You described: unused arrays, that if you remove, your program gives incorrect answers.  One possibility is that some  other arrays that are used are declared too small.  That after the removal of the used arrays these arrays are overlapping in memory and being changed incorrectly because of the overlap.  Before, when you had the extra arrays, by luck, they were providing extra storage for the array or arrays that were too small.

You could test for this by initializing the unused arrays and then at the end of the program seeing whether any of their values changed.

You could review the dimensions of all of the arrays.

Having all procedures (subroutines and functions) in modules so that their interfaces are known to the compiler will allow the compiler to check for consistency between the actual arguments with which they are called and their dummy arguments.   The `external` statement suggests that you are not making use of this help provided by Fortran >=90.

Using all error and warning options of your compiler, including run-time subscript checking, might reveal the problem.  If the array has been passed to a subroutine in a way that information is lost about its dimensions, this may not help.  With gfortran, try: `-fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -fbacktrace`

Comment: This is my speculative explanation.  The unused arrays are actually creating a buffer and one of the functions are exceeding the boundary of a bordering array.  I would have thought that would cause a runtime error though.  It seems strange I could allocate(a(10)), allocate(b(10)), and store something in a(11) = b(1) without any errors occurring.

Comment: The default is not to check the correctness of subscript usage. That checking requires extra instructions which has a runtime cost.  With gfortran you can add this checking with `-fcheck=all` (which includes `-fcheck=bounds`).   It may or may not find a subscript error, depending on how you are passing arrays to subroutines.